# Create UUID with zeros

Tags: java, scala, uuid

I'm trying to generate a UUID with all zeros:

```
java.util.UUID fromString "00000000-00000000-00000000-00000000"
```

The error is

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid UUID string: 00000000-00000000-00000000-00000000
    at java.util.UUID.fromString(UUID.java:194)
```

What am I doing wrong?

I want to create either "MinValue"  or "Invalid" UUID.

Comment: I believe (and hope) than an all zeros UUID is invalid! Otherwise [uuid_is_null(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/uuid_is_null.3.html) won't make sense.

Comment: As the error says, that's not a valid UUID.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, I want it to be either "MinValue" or "Invalid".

Comment: `IllegalArgumentException - If name does not conform to the string representation as described in toString()` So check [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#toString()) and see what is not correct.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

try this

```
System.out.println(new UUID(0,0));
```

it prints

```
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

this is the right format to use in `UUID.fromString`

Answer (score 16):

Isn't it supposed to be 8-4-4-4-12? like this:
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

Comment: Yes, you can try it here:
http://www.tryjava8.com/app/snippets/52c17184e4b00bdc99e8a92f

Comment: May i know why is this format used? Is it based on some spec or standard?

Comment: [they are indeed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Standards).

Answer (score 4):

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Nil_UUID:

> The "nil" UUID, a special case, is the UUID, 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000; that is, all bits set to zero.

The dashes should follow the normal 8-4-4-4-12 format because that's what the standards say to use and many (most?) tools enforce that on input.

Some tools *may* accept other formats, e.g. 32 hex digits with no dashes, because they just remove the dashes (if present) before validation anyway, but the particular tool you're using is a bit stricter/smarter, which shows that using non-standard formats is a bad habit that will end up biting you.

Answer (score 1):

UUIDs are standardized identifiers with various versions. UUID version 4 (UUIDv4) adheres to a specific format and is composed of 32 hexadecimal digits separated into five groups in the pattern 8-4-4-4-12, totaling 36 characters, including hyphens.

To validate a UUIDv4 manually, there are specific checks you can perform on the input string:

1. **Length Check:** Ensure the UUID string length is 36 characters.
2. **Positional Checks:** Confirm the positions of hyphens in the string at indices 8, 13, 18, and 23.
3. **Version Identification:** UUIDv4 contains a '4' at the 15th position.
4. **Content Check:** The UUIDv4 should contain at least one of '8', '9', 'a', or 'b' at the 20th position.

The UUID version 4 with zeros could be:

- 00000000-0000-4000-8000-000000000000
- 00000000-0000-4000-9000-000000000000
- 00000000-0000-4000-a000-000000000000
- 00000000-0000-4000-b000-000000000000