# Create UUID with Zeros in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, uuid, zero

**In python how can a UUID be created with all zero values?**

There is [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20840256/create-uuid-with-zeros) that is asked and answered for java, this question is specific to python.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html#uuid.UUID):

```
import uuid
uuid.UUID(int=0)
# UUID('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`UUID`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html#uuid.UUID) class, specifically, create it from the `int` `0`:

```py
import uuid
zero_uuid = uuid.UUID(int = 0)
```